# Pyplot legend index error: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, matplotlib

After defining `ax1=fig1.add_subplot(111)` and plotting 8 data series with associated `label` values, I used the following line of code to add a legend.

```
ax1.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))
```

I have used this method many times before without a problem, but on this occasion it produces an error saying `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "interface_tension_adhesion_plotter.py", line 45, in <module>
      ax1.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 564, in legend
      self.legend_ = mlegend.Legend(self, handles, labels, **kwargs)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/legend.py", line 386, in __init__
      self._init_legend_box(handles, labels, markerfirst)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/legend.py", line 655, in _init_legend_box
      fontsize, handlebox))
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/legend_handler.py", line 119, in legend_artist
      fontsize, handlebox.get_transform()) 
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/legend_handler.py", line 476, in create_artists
      self.update_prop(coll, barlinecols[0], legend)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I have no idea why this is happening and would really appreciate suggestions.

Comment: This seems to be related to the plotting of errorbars. But in order to help you, you'd need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: It is indeed plotted with error bars: `ax1.errorbar(tensionsarray,meanproportionsarray,yerr=stdproportionsarray,label="adhsion={:02.1f}".format(l))`

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. [Edit] your question if you want to provide more information.

Comment: Your point about error bars was sufficient to find a workaround: by removing error bars from the list of handles, the code worked. 
`handles, labels = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
# remove the errorbars
handles = [h[0] for h in handles]
ax1.legend(handles, labels,loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))`

Comment: If you found an answer you have two options, (A) if you think that this question and its anser can be useful for others, you may write an answer yourself (and accept it after 2 days, such that the question will not stay unsolved), or (B) if you don't think that this is useful for anyone in the future, you may delete the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If data is intact and arrays are not empty, this code works perfectly.

```
fig = plt.gcf()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

for i in range(8):
    x = np.arange(10)
    y = i + random.rand(10)
    yerr = .1*y
    l = .1*i
    ax.errorbar(x,y,yerr=yerr,label="adhsion={:02.1f}".format(l))

ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))
```

[image]

2. I had same error when I applied a filter to my data and got **empty arrays**. This could be reproduced as follows:

```
fig = plt.gcf()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

for i in range(8):
    x = np.arange(10)
    y = i + random.rand(10)
    yerr = .1*y
    l = .1*i
    if i == 7:
        ind = np.isnan(y)
        y = y[ind]
        x = x[ind]
        yerr = yerr[ind]
    ax.errorbar(x,y,yerr=yerr,label="adhsion={:02.1f}".format(l))

ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))
```

This code gives identical Traceback as in the question. **Empty array** for errors results in wrong handles for errorbars.

Workaround mentioned by @crevell:

```
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles = [h[0] for h in handles]
ax.legend(handles, labels,loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))
```

It works, but legend appears without errorbar lines.

[image]

So one should check the data supplied to the matplotlib errorbar function.